# How do I Time Stamp on a specific Lead Ownership Change?

Tags: leads, datetime, ownership

How do I create a `NOW()` time stamp when a `Lead` changes `OwnerId` from Queue X to Queue Y? In addition, I will need to create a time stamp when a checkbox gets checked on the record.

I've tried the following criterion without success:

```
AND(PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = "00Gj0000001Hoyp", Owner:Queue.Id = "00Gj0000001YmxF")
```

Comment: Adrian, it isn't working, I believe, because I need to track the Lead Ownership change from one queue to another.

AND(PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) = "00Gj0000001Hoyp", Owner:Queue.Id = "00Gj0000001YmxF")

Comment: That is checking for one specific change. You should check for all changes...use `ISCHANGED`. Also please post what you have tried **in your question** along with what specifically is not working.

Comment: So, if I need to stamp a field when Owner has changed from one queue to the other, how do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing a specific `PRIORVALUE` to the current value, use `ISCHANGED`:

```
ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
```

For a checkbox, you would also want to check that it becomes `true`:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(MyCheckbox__c),
    MyCheckbox__c = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Adrian, how will ISCHANGED help me identify that it was last "x" queue and is now "y" queue? Meaning, I need to compare both values, not just the fact that is has changed. I need to only datetime stamp the custom field if it's changed FROM a specific queue TO a specific queue.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear about what you are looking for...

Comment: I have two queues. Leads will be in Queue X. I want to datetime stamp a field ONLY when the Lead changes from Queue X to Queue Y. The change will be handled by our Marketing software.